# For loop error on a very simple program [Python]

Tags: python, python-2.7, nameerror

Whenever I try to run the follwing code:

```
message = raw_input("Write a word: ")

for i in range (message(len)):
    print i
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\testing.py", line 3, in <module>
    for i in range (message(len)):
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

I have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: What do you want to do with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply len to the string, not the other way round.

This will work:

```
for i in range (len(message)):
    print i
```

Note that this will print integers. You might actually want to do `print message[i]` to print each character in the string?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `range(len(message))`, not `range(message(len))`. Your program will then print `0`, `1`, `2`, etc. for each character in the string.